# Django CharField with dynamic default value

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I want to add a new field to a PostgreSQL database.

It's a not null and unique CharField, like

```
dyn = models.CharField(max_length=31, null=False, unique=True)
```

The database already has relevant records, so it's not an option to

- delete the database
- reset the migrations
- wipe the data
- set a default static value.

How to proceed?

---

### Edit

Tried to add a `default=uuid.uuid4`

```
dyn = models.CharField(max_length=31, null=False, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

but then I get

> Ensure this value has at most 31 characters (it has 36).

---

### Edit 2

If I create a function with [.hex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID.hex) ([as found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48438640/5675325))

```
def hex_uuid():
    """
    The UUID as a 32-character lowercase hexadecimal string
    """
    return uuid.uuid4().hex
```

and use it in the default

```
dyn = models.CharField(max_length=31, null=False, unique=True, default=hex_uuid)
```

I'll get

> Ensure this value has at most 31 characters (it has 32).

***Note***: I don't want to simply get a substring of the result, like adjusting the `hex_uuid()` to have `return str(uuid.uuid4())[:30]`, since that'll increase the collision chances.

Comment: What will be the new field value? I’m guessing you ll have to derive it right? From the each record

Comment: Using UUID4 as default is no-go?

Comment: @TrueGopnik that'd have been a great and simple idea but passes the max_length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [one of the methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56398787/5675325) shown by Oleg

```
def dynamic_default_value():
    """
    This function will be called when a default value is needed.
    It'll return a 31 length string with a-z, 0-9.
    """
    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choices(alphabet, k=31)) # 31 is the length of the string
```

with

```
dyn = models.CharField(max_length=31, null=False, unique=True, default=dynamic_default_value)
```

---

If the field was max_length of 32 characters then I'd have used the `hex_uuid()` present in the question.

---

If I wanted to make the dynamic field the same as the `id` of another existing unique field in the same model, then [I'd go through the following steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66785579/5675325).

Answer (score 0):

you can reset the migrations or edit it or create new one like:

```
python manage.py makemigrations name_you_want
```

after that:

```
python manage.py migrate same_name
```

edit:
example for funcation:

```
def generate_default_data():
    return datetime.now()

class MyModel(models.Model):
     field = models.DateTimeField(default=generate_default_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Hashem but I don't want to reset the migrations or that kind of gymnastics (as I mentioned in the question).

Comment: He wants to add value to that field which is unique and not null and not also default. Which is not achievable by only running migration or editing it

Comment: I got you, you can put default value as a function, in this function you can generate unique value for example with uuid4